# What was the .txt file which allows clangd to understand with what compile arguments a program gets compiled in?

Tags: clangd

I remember that there's a ".txt" file which allows to define link/compile-time arguments, but I've forgotten it's name.

I tried to google for answer.

Answer (score 1):

The text file is called `compile_flags.txt`.

It's discussed at https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#compile_flagstxt.

Note that there are some shortcomings of `compile_flags.txt` compared to the more common way of configuring a project for use with clang-based tooling, [`compile_commands.json`](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#compile_commandsjson); most notably, clangd won't index your project with `compile_flags.txt`.